# Read/Send SMS and Make Calls on Flip Phone via Rooted Android?

Tags: sms, bluetooth, remote-control, hands-free, bluetooth-hsp

I have a Verizon LG-VN251S Cosmos 3, and a T-Mobile Samsung Galaxy S3 (rooted; custom android 7.1 Nougat ROM). The Cosmos states in its Bluetooth menu that it has the following "Supported Profiles":

- Headset
- Handsfree
- Stereo
- Phonebook Access
- Object Push
- File Transfer
- Message Access

So-far, I haven't been able to find an app, program, or terminal command that can achieve this. Does anybody have a lead?